# or like in my SQL query (generated with CodeIgniter) not working with jQuery DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I have an array like:

```
$expl = Array([0] => 51465, [1] => 411002);
```

I want to get all records that contain zip codes like `51465` or `411002`. To get this I tried:

```
foreach ($expl as $exp) {
    $this->datatables->or_like('vendor.zip', $exp);
}
```

But this is showing me the following error:

> Call to undefined method Datatables::or_like()

Can someone please tell me the solution or any alternative way for this?

Comment: which version of `CI`?

Comment: CI version :-  3.1.3

Comment: Is `$this->datatables` an  instance  of `DB`?

Comment: yes it is, 
I have used Jquery Datatable.

Comment: The entire query looks like 

            $this->datatables->select(*);
            $this->datatables->join( join conditions );
            $expl = explode(',', LOGINZIP);
            foreach ($expl as $exp) {
                $this->datatables->or_like('vendor.zip', $exp);
            }
            $this->datatables->from('products');

Comment: Could you paste your all method code?

Answer (score 1):

Please use database Codeigniter object db or you can use custom datatables.
I would suggest you please use db object.

```
$this->db->or_like('vendor.zip', $exp);
```

But you should also use "IN" query.

```
$names = array(51465, 411002);
$this->db->where_in('vendor.zip', $names); // Here vendor is alias of table name 
// Produces: WHERE vendor.zip IN (51465, 411002)
```

Comment: I can not use database Codeigniter object db with DataTables, and this works with database Codeigniter object db but i can not use this in DataTables

Comment: DataTable is jQuery lib. If you want to fetch records from database then you should use other database CI object or db. You can not mix dataTable with CI query. But could you please share some more code, I would happy to help you.

Comment: calling method to get data
$(document).ready(function () {
oTable = $('#getData').dataTable({
'sAjaxSource': '<?= site_url('admin/Product_controller/getproductsdata/pending') ?>',
// in admin/Product_controller/getproductsdata/pending ('codeignitor controller')
$this->datatables->select(*);$this->datatables->join('vendor', 'vendor.vid = products.vendorid');$expl = explode(',', LOGINZIP);foreach ($expl as $exp) {$this->datatables->like('vendor.zip', $exp);}$this->datatables->from('products');
            echo $this->datatables->generate();

Comment: I have read your code. Please replace "datatables" with "db".
and add $this->load->database(); into your model or controller

Comment: But i want this in DataTables, then only i would be able to perform more operations on this, replacing db with datatables will convert the code into codeignitor but i want this in datatables only.
Please help me with this.

Comment: But your ajax called the controller of CI. Hence, datatables object is not working. But you should use datatable object using  $databales = $this->load->database(); method.

Comment: and you can not perform database operations from jQuery DataTable directly. You must have to use server support for that.

Comment: i can do this if i will use $this->datatables->like('vendor.zip', $exp); but i want to use $this->datatables->or_like('vendor.zip', $exp);

Comment: $this->datatables->or_like('vendor.zip', $exp); Please replace this code with $this->datatables->where_in('vendor.zip', $exp);

Comment: Gives me an error :- 
 Call to undefined method Datatables::where_in()

Comment: Might be you are using third party custom lib for dataTable for CI database. Hence, I have suggested you that please use CI default thing its should be good for us.

Comment: yes thanks a lot for your help but i can not use CI instead of datatables.

Comment: why sir? You can not used?